# SQL to delete pairs if one row is older than a certain timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with two columns:

```
match_id varchar2(30)
timestamp
```

match_id is in format of integer.[A|B], such as 1234.A, 1234.B, 1235.A or 1235.B. rows with match_id on same integer is called a pair, so 1234.A and 1234.B is a pair while 1235.A and 1235.B is another pair.

Requirement is to delete all pairs if one row in this pair is older than certain timestamp. Database is Oracle 11.2 or higher.

I'm not good at SQL so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the following...

```
create table test_1
```

(
match_id varchar2(30),
ts timestamp
);

```
insert into test_1 values ('1234.A',current_timestamp-10);
insert into test_1 values ('1234.B',current_timestamp-20);
insert into test_1 values ('1235.A',current_timestamp-30);
insert into test_1 values ('1235.B',current_timestamp-40);
```

TO get the content of the table.

```
select * from test_1;
```

1234.A  09-JAN-17 08.55.24.000000000 AM
1234.B  30-DEC-16 08.56.02.000000000 AM
1235.A  20-DEC-16 08.56.02.000000000 AM
1235.B  10-DEC-16 08.56.02.000000000 AM

Would delete all teh pairs whose timestamp is less than "current_timestamp-30".

```
delete test_1 where substr(match_id,1,instr(match_id,'.')-1) in (select substr(match_id,1,instr(match_id,'.')-1) from test_1 where ts < current_timestamp-30);

select * from test_1;
```

1234.A  09-JAN-17 08.55.24.000000000 AM
1234.B  30-DEC-16 08.56.02.000000000 AM

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal data model! Two bits of information, the integer and the (A|B) part, stored in one column!

I can't test the solution below (no test data provided), but something like this should work:

```
delete from your_table_name
where substr(match_id, 1, instr(match_id, '.')) 
         in (
               select substr(match_id, 1, instr(match_id, '.')) 
               from   your_table_name
               where  timestamp_column <= :input_timestamp_value
            )
;
```